# Attribute Error Issue 'User' object has no attribute 'roles'

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm having a slight issue checking for roles a user has. I'm currently getting a

`if member_role in message.author.roles]
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'roles'`

It seems I cannot pass `roles` with the `message` argument when checking to see if the message author has them roles.

Help Appreciated.

Here is my code I'm working with:

```
   async def on_message(self, message):
        if not isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel) or 
message.author.id == self.bot.user.id:
            # not a DM, or it's just the bot itself
            return

    channel = self.bot.get_channel(578731262550736910)
    if not channel:
        print("Mail channel not found! Reconfigure bot!")
    time = datetime.utcnow()
    guild = self.bot.get_guild(555844758778544158)
    member_role = get(guild.roles, name='Members')
    muted_role = get(guild.roles, name='Modmail Muted')

    content = message.clean_content
    verified = [member for member in guild.members 
               if member_role in message.author.roles]

    muted = [member for member in guild.members 
               if muted_role in message.author.roles]

    if muted:
        await message.channel.send("You're not allowed to use modmail.")
        return

    if verified:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=" You've got modmail!")
        embed.add_field(name="Sent by:", value=f"{message.author.mention} ({message.author.id})" ,inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Message:", value=content[:1000] or "blank")
        embed.set_footer(text="Mods: React with icon below this message to notify us that you're dealing with this modmail. (First reaction    already set by the bot)")
        if message.attachments:
            embed.add_field(name="Attachments", value=", ".join([i.url for i in message.attachments]))
        if len(content[1000:]) > 0:
            embed.add_field(name="Message (continued):", value=content[1000:])
        msg = await channel.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction('')
        try:
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Thanks {message.author.display_name}! your message has been sent to the Mods.", timestamp=time)
            embed.set_footer(text="Message Sent")
            await message.add_reaction('')
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        except discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError:
            await message.channel.send('')
        else:
            await message.channel.send("Only members can use modmail.")
```

Comment: Is it a private channel? It may [affect](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/legacy/api.html#discord.Message.author) the type of author (User/Member)

Comment: It is a direct message initiated with the bot, I assume that is a private channel. The documentation is telling me if it's a private channel it's `User` yet this is not working for me either.

Comment: `User`s don't have roles, `Member`s do.  A `Member` is a user in the context of their membership with a particular server/guild, which includes the roles they have in that server.  Say your bot interacts with someone in a private message that it shares two servers with: which roles does it modify? If you have a specific server in mind, you'll have to use the [`get_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member) method of the `Guild` object representing that server.

Answer (score 1):

as suggested by @Patrick Haugh in replies I used `get_member`.

```
user_id = message.author.id
author = guild.get_member(user_id)
```